# Angular js Bootstrap Date binding

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, date

I am new to AngularJs and Bootstrap. I am having trouble with date  binding.
My JSON has a date in YYYY-MM-DD format, but it is not binding with the Bootstrap date control.

Is it not possible with out directives or any other UI library (like angular strap or UI etc)

I have created plunker, please let me know if I have made some mistakes

http://plnkr.co/edit/FUjgepdJwC3N5iU6Cqlw?p=preview

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.11/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="panel-body" ng-controller="ActionPlanDetailCtrl">
        <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="id">ID</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputId" placeholder="ID" ng-model="actionPlan.id"
                    title="ID"
                >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="visitDate">Visit Date</label> <input type="date" name="inputVisitDate" ng-model="actionPlan.visitDate"
                    class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd"
                >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Subject</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSubject" placeholder="Subject"
                    ng-model="actionPlan.subject" title="subject"
                >
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
  'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', [ 'dealerActionPlanModule' ]);

angular.module('dealerActionPlanModule', []);

/* Controllers */

angular.module('dealerActionPlanModule');

angular.module('dealerActionPlanModule').controller('ActionPlanDetailCtrl',
        [ '$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.actionPlan =  {
                id : '123',
                region : 'North',
                visitDate : '2014-01-01',
                subject : 'High Complaint in May'
            } ;
        } ]);
```

Note : I prefer to have simple solution, as I am new to Java Script and angular JS (Basically a java guy)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you have declared your date in string format and your <input type="date"/> accepts date format only, not string format. so for your example change input type to 'text' and it will work. OR you have to convert your string format into date format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is convert your string to Date object please see here

http://plnkr.co/edit/i1dsnV4pZqIuIArRgqTl?p=preview

```
angular.module('dealerActionPlanModule').controller('ActionPlanDetailCtrl',
        [ '$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.actionPlan =  {
                id : '123',
                region : 'North',
                visitDate : '2014-02-01',
                subject : 'High Complaint in May'
            } ;
                $scope.actionPlan.visitDate =new Date( Date.parse(  $scope.actionPlan.visitDate));

        } ]);
```

Comment: HI, If i get the data from server/ json file, it does not work. I have update the Plunker to use factory http://plnkr.co/edit/FUjgepdJwC3N5iU6Cqlw?p=preview can you take a look at it

Comment: if you using resource you need first resolve your call and after that format date please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/ZKZN1YG5789WyYJPgSSD?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('dealerActionPlanModule').controller('ActionPlanDetailCtrl',
    [ '$scope','$filter', function($scope,$filter) {
        $scope.actionPlan =  {
            id : '123',
            region : 'North',
            visitDate : new Date('2014-02-01'),
            subject : 'High Complaint in May'
        } ;



    $scope.date=    $filter('date')($scope.actionPlan.visitDate, 'medium')
    $scope.date1=$filter('date')($scope.actionPlan.visitDate, 'shortDate')
    console.log($scope.date);
    console.log($scope.date1);

    } ]);
```

Comment: Though this will work, I have to choose @sylwester answer. Because for example purpose I have hard coded the data(actionPlan), but actually it will be served by web service in that scenario I am not sure how we can have 'new Date('2014-02-01')'. thanks for your answer

Comment: as you have asked for date format, you can use $filter service you got to inject it into function and can use it as shown above.